# Is this possible of deployment of asp.net mvc application, without dll in iis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

If I want to deploy my asp.net mvc application in iis (any version it may be) with code , means without any publishing. then is it must that its bin dir have the dll which is nameed by application name? Can I deploy application without its dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is feasible with MVC but if you want source code in your IIS server (why would you???) you need to use a [web site in contrast to web application](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx) when creating your MVC project. Notice that this is **not** what the default template uses, meaning that you have to create everything manually from scratch.

This being said, this is not the recommended way of working with ASP.NET MVC. It is preferred to have a web application which is precompiled. For compiling you could use either the publishing functionality or take a look at [Building a Web Deployment Package](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx) or take a look at [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd&displaylang=en) as well ([blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx)).

Comment: Ok thanks , I think also we can not deploy asp.net MVc application without its dll.